# intersectsWithObject between objects in and not in activeSelectio

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

intersectsWithObject between objects in and not in activeSelection
I am using fabricJS 4.3.1.

When an object is part of an active selection of multiple objects, the this.intesectsWithObject no longer returns true for objects it is "intersecting" with that are not part of the selection.

How to detected if it intersects with object regardless of the activeSelection? Thanks!

Currently trying to override intersectsWithObject and if they are in and outside the active selection, so adjust the coordinates using the top left of the active-selection and accounting for the local active-selection centered coordinates.